# How to import Cloud Firestore Timestamp object from the Firebase SDK?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple class that is operating on `Timestamp`s:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'

export class Activity {
  public id:string
  public name:string
  public color:string
  public lastEventAt:firebase.firestore.Timestamp
  ⋮
}
```

I would like to access the type in the class without specifying the namespace like:

```
public lastEventAt:Timestamp
```

What should my `import` statement look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to abbreviate Timestamp from the firestore namespace, the easiest thing to do might just be this:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'

import Timestamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp

export class Activity {
  public id:string
  public name:string
  public color:string
  public lastEventAt:Timestamp
  ⋮
}
```

It works equally well for me to create a type alias:

```
type Timestamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp
```

TypeScript will figure out that it's the same as other types that point to the same Timestamp class.

Answer (score 2):

From Firebase 9 you can import timestamp like this:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat';
import Timestamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp;
```

For previous versions use this solution:

```
import {firestore} from 'firebase/app';
import Timestamp = firestore.Timestamp;
```